# Are raster color band codes standardized in ArcMap/ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, colormap

I have multiple TIFF files which contain rainfall data. Different colours are associated with different levels of rainfall.

When I add the files to arcgis, a colour/colour code is created.

[image: Colour Codes for TIFF File]

[image: Colour Codes for TIFF Files 2]

These two images represent the colours/colour codes for two different TIFF files.

On first glance, it appears that ArcGIS assigns the same code to the same colour, however what I would like to know is if this is guaranteed? As in, will a shade of blue in one TIFF file have the same code as a shade of blue in another TIFF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the assigned colors can differ. However, you can check the symbology of your TIFF files. There you can find how raster values are assigned to a colour or colour scale.

There you can make sure they are symbolized in the same way.

`Apply Symbology From Layer (Data Management)` might be available to you depending on your ArcGIS version. I have not used it before.